# How to tell when the A* algorithm is a good option, and how to choose a good heuristic?

Tags: algorithm, a-star, heuristics

Recently I wrote a solver for the famous "15 puzzle" using the A* algorithm by using a heuristic function based off the sum of the Manhattan distances of the distances for each tile to their destination spots.

This led me to wonder two things:

1. How do you know when the A* algorithm is even something to use? Unless I came across online tutorials, I would have never guessed that the 15 puzzle could be solved this way.
2. How do you know which heuristic function to use? At first, for the 15 puzzle, I considered a simple "sum of tiles not in position" heuristic. So if all pieces weren't in their right spots, the heuristic for the 15 puzzle might return 15, whereas 0 would indicate a solved board. But somehow the sum of the distances are better. How does one know, going into it?

Comment: This looks like it would be better at Math.se to me.

Comment: It may be a better fit for [cs.SE]. But [math.SE] is a good choice.

Comment: "But somehow the sum of the distances are better" -- this is easy to see, because you can see that for each tile separately, the Manhattan-distance-to-home value is always *at least as high* as the other heuristic.  If the tile is home, both heuristics give 0; if not, is-displaced gives 1, while Manhattan-distance-to-home gives *at least* 1.  Summing over all tiles, each term in the sum for MDTH is at least as high as for ID, so the final sum is too.

Comment: There is no mechanical, systematic way to find a good heuristic for A*.  Really all you have to start with is (as harold said) the knowledge that solving a relaxation of the original problem (i.e., the same problem but with some constraints removed) will give you a valid lower bound.  But there are an infinite number of ways to relax a problem, and only some of them (or sometimes none!) are both (1) computationally feasible and (2) often provide good bounds in practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're exploring a graph to find a path that is in some way "shortest" (the cost doesn't have to be a "distance", but it has to be monotone), you can already use Dijkstra's. Your problem will typically look nothing like path-finding at a first glance though, as in, you're not planning to "travel over a route". It's more abstract than that.

Then if you can use Dijkstra *and* you have some admissible heuristic (that's the hard part), you can use A*.

An often used technique for finding heuristics is dropping some constraint of your problem. For example, if you can teleport each tile to its destination regardless of whether there's already a tile there, it will take #displacements teleports. So there's the first heuristic. If you have to slide the tiles but they can slide through each other, the cost for each tile is the Manhattan distance to its destination. Then you can look at improving the heuristic, for example the Manhattan distance heuristic obviously ignores that tiles interfere with each other as they move, but there is a simple case where we know where tiles must conflict and use more moves: consider two tiles (pretend there are no other tiles) in the same row and their destinations are also on that row but in order to get there they'd have to pass through each other. They'd have to go around each other, adding two vertical moves. This gives the Linear Conflicts heuristic. Even more interference can be taken into account, for example with pattern databases.

Comment: Also you have to be careful that your heuristic doesn't count any move twice or more.  E.g. with the "linear conflicts" heuristic you suggest, it might be that those 2 vertical moves also enable some pair on an adjacent row to be swapped *at the same time* -- if so, you would only be allowed to count those 2 vertical moves for *one* of the rows.  Or it might be that you can prove that "fixing" each row nevertheless requires 2 vertical moves *regardless* of interference from neighbouring rows -- but this isn't obvious, so it requires proof.

Comment: @j_random_hacker proof is given in "Generating Admissible Heuristics by Criticizing Solutions to Relaxed Models"

Comment: That appears to be a 1985 paper (technical report?) by Hansson, Mayer and Yung.  Looks interesting!